# Create security group at CLI, getting InvalidVpcID.NotFound The vpc ID does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

Trying to issue:

```
$ aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name Grp1 --description Grp1 --vpc-id vpc-0e6f748e8c01534bc
```

But I get

```
An error occurred (InvalidVpcID.NotFound) when calling the CreateSecurityGroup operation:  
The vpc ID 'vpc-0e6f748e8c01534bc' does not exist
```

That vpc does exists, but it isn't being recognized.
It is in a different region.
I can't specify region in the command.
How do I get around that?

[image]

Comment: Check your cli region is the same as the vpc. Region can be found by `aws configure`.

Comment: I am in a different region (`aws configure list`) is the command we want.  So how do do I do a security group in a region different from my default.  I thought the fact I had to pick the VPC would take of that given it implies region.

Comment: try to add `--region <region>` where the region example is `us-east-1`

Comment: That worked.  I had looked for it in the help and not seen it.  Thanks!  The answer is region if you'd like to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do some command on the aws cli, you can submit the region option as follows.

```
aws cli <some code> --region <region>
```

The cli options are listed in the aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html).